# Python expected_conditions don't always work

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, web-scraping

I'm having an odd problem trying to web scrape some data from ESPN.  I have the below code that sometimes works as intended, but sometimes will get hung up trying to log in. It really seems random, and I'm not sure what's going on.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'Source')

driver.get("http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin")
WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)")))
frms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//iframe)")

driver.switch_to_frame(frms[2])
time.sleep(2)

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'(//input)[1]')))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input)[1]").send_keys("Username")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input)[2]").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button").click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
time.sleep(2)
```

When I run the code as is, it often times times out during the second "WebDriverWait", despite the page having fully loaded in chrome.  If I take that line out, I then will get an error message that reads:

"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

Answer (score 0):

You check this xpath? Apparently it is not correct, you can try it on the browser console.

```
$x('yourxpath')
```

Comment: Sorry, a bit of a newb, but where am I supposed to put that code?

Comment: In chrome, press F12 and go to the console tab

Comment: I tried that, and the xpath is correct.  Like I said, sometimes it works, other times it doesn't, and there's really no rhyme or reason for it that I can see.